# Any way / plugin to prevent accidental update in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find out a solution to prevent accidental destructive queries on database.
For example: something which convert my update statement to select or select count(), and tells me what I am going to update?

I always run select first to see whether my where condition is correct or not. But is there any way to automate it?

I could write a small program to simply convert any update statement to select and run it first, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if something is already there.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and answers.

Comment: Connect as a user with no `update` privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools - Preferences - Database - Advanced and make sure Autocommit is unchecked.

When Autocommit is unchecked, when you make changes to the database you have to manually Commit them - click the icon in the SQL worksheet toolbar with the database and the green tick in front of it.

If you want to rollback your changes, the icon next to it (with the red cross) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Create a View from the table and write an "INSTEAD OF" Trigger. There you can do whatever you like.